# RabbitMQ channel shutdown with channel error with unknown delivery tag

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm seeing below error after every message I receive from rabbitMQ ,

> Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
> o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer -            : Restarting Consumer@3d5a462b: tags=[{amq.ctag-zGA1v36aEmXxnG7bqBUcdg=asstMgmt.queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://mqadmin@xx:xx:xx:xx:5672/assetmgmt,1165), conn: Proxy@5c87dd9e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@2ec6c89 [delegate=amqp://mqadmin@@xx:xx:xx:xx:5672/assetmgmt, localPort= port], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

Messages are not lost, the consumption and processing is fine, But, If observed above amqp://mqadmin@@xx:xx:xx:xx:5672/assetmgmt,1165.. 1165 channels got created .,and it doesn't stop there, it keeps on happening with every message consumed.

Below is my configuration:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("amConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(env.getProperty("assetMgmt.rabbitmq.host"));
    connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("assetMgmt.port")));
    connectionFactory.setUsername(env.getProperty("assetMgmt.username"));
    connectionFactory.setPassword(env.getProperty("assetMgmt.password"));
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(env.getProperty("assetMgmt.virtual.host"));
    connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(5);
    //connectionFactory.setChannelCheckoutTimeout(100000);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("umConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory umConnectionFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.host"));
    connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.port")));
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host"));
    connectionFactory.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.username"));
    connectionFactory.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.rabbitmq.password"));
    connectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(5);
    //connectionFactory.setChannelCheckoutTimeout(100000);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory assetContainerFactory(
        @Qualifier("connectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(6);
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory umContainerFactory(
        @Qualifier("umConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory umConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(umConnectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(6);
    factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(umConnectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    return factory;
}
```

I needed 2 instances, as we need to connect on 2 virtual hosts for different instances.
and below is the code on what happens once we recieve the message

```
     @RabbitListener(admin = "amqpAssetMgmtAdmin" ,queues = "${asstMgmt.queue.name}",
              containerFactory = "assetContainerFactory")
            public void loadAssetMgmtData(Message msg,Channel channel) throws IOException {
            long tag =0;
        try {

        UDDAO dao = new UDDAO();
        dao.setAssetMgmtRabbitTemplate(assetMgmtRabbitTemplate);
        Map<String, Object> headers = msg.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        String msgType = (String) headers.get("type");
        String payload = new String(msg.getBody());
        tag = msg.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();
        if(msgType == null || msgType.isEmpty()){
            log.error("Got message with empty message type, rejecting the message");
            channel.basicReject(tag, false);
        }
              //Process the message
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);

    }  catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
        log.error("DB exception so requeueing the message");
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        if(tag>0)
            channel.basicReject(tag, true);

    }catch (Exception e) {
        if(msg.getMessageProperties().getRedelivered()){
            log.error("Internal server error occurred. rejecting without requeueing ", e);
            if(tag>0)
            channel.basicReject(tag, false);
        }else{
            if(tag>0)
            channel.basicReject(tag, true);
            log.error("Internal server error occurred. rejecting and requeuing ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time. Please help me understand, where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On care fully watching the logs , found that acknowledgeMode=AUTO, and whenever my code is acknowledging the conusmed message channel.basicAck(tag, false), It is throwing the warning and the channel is stopping and a new one is getting created. As my code needs manual acknowledgement, I have set factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL); It solved the problem.